# EV of probability given outcome

Tags: probability

Michael has a crush on a girl. Every night, he texts her and asks to go on a date. There is a 1/7
chance that the girl
says yes, a 2/7
chance that the girl says no, and a 4/7 chance that the girl asks Michael to text her again tomorrow, which
Michael does. Given that she said no, what is the expected number of days it took her to decide?

Comment: Does it repeat until she says yes or no and is the probability the same every day?

Comment: yeah but the correct answer isn't 7/4-- this is really confusing me up

Comment: I personally think the equation to solve would be $(1/3)+(1/3)(2/3)*n=1/2$ where n is the proportion of day 2, and after solving I get n =3/4 so the EV of day rejecting him should be $7/4$

Comment: 3 apparently isn't on the answer choice

Comment: yeah 2 is one of the option-- can you show me why this is the case? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice the following equality
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n\left(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{2}{7}\right)=1,
\end{equation}
where you can use the geometric series to prove that.  Clearly the first element of the sum is the probability of yes, and the second is the probability of no.  We can also see that the probability of yes is $\frac{1}{3}$, and no is $\frac{2}{3}$.  We know she said no, so we normalize the probability by multiplying by $3/2$, and the expected number of days is 
\begin{equation}
\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{7}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^n=\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{7}\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^2=\frac{7}{3},
\end{equation}
where we have used the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, found in wikipedia on geometric series.  We have assumed that the first day would mean one day.  If you assumed that a no on the first day is $0$, then you would subtract another geometric series, giving $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: Note that the answer is actually unaffected by the stated condition of ending with a "no" -- the expected time to decide is 7/3, whether unconditional, with a yes, or a no. Because the probability of the two events that end the chain are the same across "time", we can make no inference from length to result, nor vice versa from result to length. The variable "length of conversation" therefore is geometrically distributed with p=3/7 ("success" probability), and has an expected value of E=1/p. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: That's an interesting point, I didn't notice that.

Comment: wait what does normalizing probability mean? I don't get this... Thanks!

Comment: @DavidP By the way can I know why there is a n+1 there? Shouldn't it be just n because we want to find the exact day of the guy being rejected?

Comment: Normalizing a probability distribution means making sure the total probability of anything happening equals 1.  In this case, because we know the answer is no, we divide by the probability that the answer is no to normalize the probability of a no being given on a certain day.  I mention at the end the ambiguity between n and n+1, depends on the way you define it.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that the No the first day is assumed to be 1.  If that were to be the case, then the expected no of days on we which she decided would be the following:

Probability of a decision made = Probability of a No + Probability of a Yes

$P(Decide) = \frac{2}{7}+\frac{1}{7} = \frac{3}{7}$

USing Bayes' theorem:

Probability of $P(No/Decided) = \dfrac{\frac{2}{7}}{\frac{3}{7}} = \frac{2}{3}$.

$P(Yes/Decided) = \dfrac{\frac{1}{7}}{\frac{3}{7}} = \frac{1}{3}$.

$P(Decided/No) = \dfrac{\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{2}{3}$

On each day it is this probability of decision that she has to make.

Thus S = Porbability of a Decision/No + Probability of not making decsion the previous day * Porbability of a Decision/No (2) + (Probability of not making decision the previous day)^2 *Porbability of a Decision/No (3) + ....

$S = \frac{2}{3}(1) + \frac{4}{7}\frac{2}{3}(2) + (\frac{4}{7})^2\frac{2}{3}(3) +\cdots$

$S = \frac{2}{3}\dfrac{1}{(1-\frac{4}{7})^2} = \frac{98}{27}$

Comment: My first approach was incorrect.    To say that we end with a No is to say that the path is (Try Again)$^n\times \frac 17$.  The probability of that occurring is, of course $p_n=\left(\frac 47\right)^n\times\frac 17$.   Of course $\sum p_n=\frac 13$.  Then $E=3\times \sum np_n=\frac 43$.

Comment: Your first approach was incorrect?!.  prob of no is $\frac{2}{7}$.  Mine does not make sense is it not?

Comment: Yes.  My first approach imagined a world in which Yes votes do not exist.  That is not valid.  Rather, one has to take the probabilities as they are, and then divide by the probability that the final answer is No.  As you correctly point out, I used the wrong probability for No, but it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Should say:  I am not entirely comfortable with my answer.  Might be worth simulating the problem.

Comment: Thank you sir!!.Makes sense

Comment: I understood the problem to mean that she could say no on the first day, a no on the second day, a no on the third day and so on....  As we have probabilities for both yes and no put together make a decision.  May be I my thinking was skewed to use Bayes' theorem